# Why can't you just call black holes "exceptions to the rule" in the black hole paradox?

Tags: black-holes, information

My understanding of the black hole information paradox can be summarised as follows: Black holes emit hawking radiation in random directions. This means that they eventually "evaporate", and so all information about the stuff which fell into the black hole is lost (as the radiation is completely uniform).

Now, I understand that it's really nice to think that we can extract the entire past from what we currently know, but I don't see why we can't just call black holes exceptions to the rule that information must be conserved?

Comment: Most physicists don’t accept that the laws of physics have any “exceptions” whatsoever. They think that if there are exceptions then this is proof that you haven’t found the right laws.